# How to set collection inline?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

For example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable() 
{ 
  Columns = new DataColumnCollection(
     { 
         new DataColumn("col1"), 
         new DataColumn("col2")
     })
});
```

Comment: This very much depends on the version of VS/.Net that you're using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are talking about the [Collection Initialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) 
feature added in C# 3.  It is done like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable() 
{ 
    Columns = 
    { 
        new DataColumn("col1"), 
        new DataColumn("col2")
    }
};
```

This does not call a collection constructor, it uses the collection which already exists in the DataTable.

This is short-hand for Columns.Add(), so it doesn't require Columns to have a setter.

You were so close with the code in your question!

Answer (score 3):

The `Columns` property does not have a setter so you can only modify it.

How about this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("col1"), new DataColumn("col2") });
```

If you want to do with one statement in a lambda:

```
DataTable table = (() => {
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("col1"),
                                   new DataColumn("col2") });
    return table;})();
```

Comment: I want to do it all inline.  I thought it was possible using () => or something.

Comment: You can't do it inline for the reasons I gave in my answer.  If you want to keep the code clean you could create an extension method to create a table and add the columns in one step, but at some point it will be at least two lines of code.

Comment: If it had a setter, how would it be done? Can you provide a working example please?

Comment: Even if `Columns` had a setter you couldn't do it because there's no constructor for `DataColumnCollection` that accepts an array of columns.

Comment: @DStanley - alright.  I guess I probably won't run into those objects very often.  I was hoping to see an example (not of datatables) that had a public constructor and public setter.  Oh well.

Comment: I'll amend my answer to show how it would work IF it had a setter and  IF you could initialize it with an array of columns.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to remove the paretheses around that collection initializer for `DataColumnCollection`, and remove the unmatched, final `)`

Those are syntactical issues, though. The underlying problems are that the `Columns` property has no setter, and the `DataColumnCollection` has no public constructor.

Basically, you have to instantiate and then call `.Columns.Add()`.

If this is something you have to do a lot in your code, you could create helper classes that would give you friendlier syntax:

```
DataTable table = DataTableFactory.CreateTableWithColumns("col1", "col2");
```

Comment: I attempted to do this.  Even if he correct the syntax error he is going to get an error saying that **Columns** is a read only property.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 reasons why this won't work:

1) the `Columns` property is read-only
2) the `DataColumnCollection` class does not have a constructor that accepts a collection of columns to initialize it.
Best you can do is create the table in one line and add the columns in another:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.AddRange( new []
     { 
         new DataColumn("col1"), 
         new DataColumn("col2")
     });
```

To answer your other question, *IF* `Columns` had a setter and *IF* `DataColumnCollection` accepted columns in its constructor the syntax would be:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable() 
{ 
  Columns = new DataColumnCollection( new DataColumn[]
     { 
         new DataColumn("col1"), 
         new DataColumn("col2")
     })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `DataColumnCollection` has no constructor so you can't manually create an instance. The compiler's error message should be pretty self-explanatory, saying something along the lines of:

> The type 'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' has no constructors defined

You can add columns to the `DataTable.Columns` collection by using the `Add()` method:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1"));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that syntax as the Columns property is readonly.  I'd use the technique suggested by Gabe.